# inotify: Echo which file has changed in directory

Tags: bash, inotify

I've just learnt [how to constantly check if file is modified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166341/constantly-check-if-file-is-modified-bash):

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify filename >/dev/null; do
    echo "filename is changed"
    # do whatever else you need to do
done
```

If I use a [directoryname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566569/how-to-continuously-monitor-the-directory-using-dnotify-inotify-command) instead of a filename I can check all files of the directory:

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify directoryname >/dev/null; do
    echo "filename is changed"
    # do whatever else you need to do
done
```

But how can I `echo` the filename of the file that has been changed?

Comment: `man inotifywait` will tell you about the `--format` option. And while you're there, take a look at enhancing your loop with `--monitor`. Finally, don't discard the output of `inotifywait`; your answer is waiting for you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inotifywait` emits a continuous set of events on the watched directory, so the recommended way would to move the watch out of the `while` loop and look for events within a new loop that looks on the output of the `inotify`. Note that this involves removing the `--quiet` flag, because the `read` command needs to see those events and read it over standard input.

```
inotifywait -m -e modify "directoryname" | 
while read -r dir action file; do
    echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$dir' via '$action'"
done
```